# Read more / Read less SwiftUI .lineLimit

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to use `.lineLimit` in SwiftUI to get "read more" and "read less" when the text is long? Hide "read more" when text is not long. For example, Facebook ,Instagram ...

My code is not working as I need.
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRrkO.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct Testing: View {
@State var fColor = Color.white
@State var bColor = Color.pink
//added
@State var isViewed = false
var body: some View {
    //added
    Button {
        //added
        isViewed.toggle()
    } label: {
        Text("When it comes to chicken there just isn’t anything more delicious than a juicy, crusty piece of finger-licking good fried chicken. It might seem intimidating to fry your own chicken, but it’s actually pretty straightforward and it puts grocery store and fast food fried chicken to shame.  If you have a thermometer for the oil and a timer, you can produce fail-proof fried chicken.  If you’ve ever wanted to make your own fried chicken, now is the time to try!")
            .foregroundColor(fColor)
            .font(.system(size: 15))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .lineLimit(isViewed ? 15 : 5) //added
            .padding()
    }
    .background(bColor)
    .cornerRadius(30)
    .padding()
  }
}
```

Comment: Add some details to your problem. This code is working and tapping on it changes shown number of lines. What is the main problem?

Comment: I want to add read more and read less

Comment: It sounds like you want a "Read More" to be a button somewhere in your view. Either in line with the end of the text, or just after the text.

To make your question clearer, I encourage screenshotting what you're trying to emulate. Provide a screenshot of that what you see in Facebook or Instagram.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRrkO.png

Answer (score 2):

Inlining the "Read More" button with the text seems tricky, but if that's what you're shooting for, it looks like there may be some steps for that [here](https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/swiftui-how-to-make-see-more-see-less-style-button-at-the-end-of-text-675f859c2c4f).

A simpler approach would just be to have the text separate from the button and place them both in a VStack:

```swift
var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text("When it comes to chicken there just isn’t anything more delicious than a juicy, crusty piece of finger-licking good fried chicken. It might seem intimidating to fry your own chicken, but it’s actually pretty straightforward and it puts grocery store and fast food fried chicken to shame.  If you have a thermometer for the oil and a timer, you can produce fail-proof fried chicken.  If you’ve ever wanted to make your own fried chicken, now is the time to try!")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(isViewed ? 15 : 5)
            Button(isViewed ? "Read Less" : "Read More" ) {
                isViewed.toggle()
            }
            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold))
        }
        .font(.system(size: 15))
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(fColor)
        .background(bColor)
        .cornerRadius(30)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, thank you. is that possible to get the "read more" at the end in same line? not in new line under the text

Comment: Yes, but you’ll need to do a lot more work to get that to happen. Please refer to [the link I mentioned above](https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/swiftui-how-to-make-see-more-see-less-style-button-at-the-end-of-text-675f859c2c4f)